# constructing a spiral

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry, polar-coordinates

picture of spiral][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NOin.png)I am seeking to construct a spiral with the constraints shown in the picture. The problem is that I have not covered polar co-ordinates and I am quite bogged down in understanding logarithmic spirals.

the main constraints of the spiral would be:

- 0.15m from center point to start of spiral (apologies if I am butchering nomenclature)
- 0.3m to the end of the spiral
- that between the two points an angle of 30 degrees
- that the distance between the edge of the spiral and the center point decrease linearly from 0.3m to 0.15m.

alternatively could someone suggest a good text book or suggest how to solve this problem?

Comment: How many loops does it make around itself?

Comment: You talk about a picture, but I don't see a picture. Also, you've tagged this [tag:polar-coordinates]. You must have tried _something_. The easiest thing you can think of will probably do the trick.

Comment: How about you go study polar coordinates for a while and then try again?

Comment: @MattiP. it makes 1 loop. it needs to be the logarithmic equation. Basically I don't understand the equation:  r=a.e^(b.theta).